# Translate SQL 'not in' into LINQ to Entities using Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework, linq

How to Translate SQL with 'not in' keywords into LINQ to Entities using Entity Framework 4?
All fields ending with 'ID' are of type integer.

```
SELECT * 
        FROM IRSampleCompletionGoal as goal_tbl
  where 
  (Cast(goal_tbl.[TermID] as nvarchar) +' '+Cast(goal_tbl.[UserID] as nvarchar)+' '+Cast(goal_tbl.[CourseID] as nvarchar)+' '+cast(goal_tbl.[StudentID] as nvarchar)+' '+cast(goal_tbl.[ObjectiveID] as nvarchar))  
  NOT IN
  (
  select (Cast([TermID] as nvarchar) +' '+Cast([UserID] as nvarchar)+' '+Cast([CourseID] as nvarchar)+' '+cast([StudentID] as nvarchar)+' '+cast([ObjectiveID] as nvarchar)) 
  from IRSampleCompletionCurrentStatistics
  where ((ArtifactID is not null) OR (NoArtifactChecked='True' ))

  )
```

Comment: Make an array then `Not thisArray.Contains("somevalue")`

Comment: Or `!thisArray.Contains("somevalue")` for C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 goal_tbl.Where(x => !IRSampleCompletionCurrentStatistics.Where(i => i.ArtifactID != null || i.NoArtifactChecked == true).Any(i => (i.TermID.ToString() + " " + i.UserID.ToString() + i.StudentID.ToString() + " " + i.ObjectiveID.ToString()) == (x.TermID.ToString()+ " " + x.UserID.ToString() + " " + x.CourseID.ToString() + " " + x.StudentID.ToString() + x.ObjectiveID.ToString()))
```

Comment: Thank you so much to all Responders! Bruniasty, could you please write the same lambda query in VB.NET syntax? How to I assign the result of this query to a variable? Like this: "Dim myvariable as IEnumerable(of IRSampleCompletionGoal) = 'your query' "  ?

Comment: I tried Dim test As IEnumerable(Of IRSampleCompletionGoal) = goal_tbl.Where(!IRSampleCompletionCurrentStatistics.Where(i => i.ArtifactID != null || i.NoArtifactChecked == true).Any(i => (i.TermID.ToString() + " " + i.UserID.ToString() + i.StudentID.ToString() + " " + i.ObjectiveID.ToString()) == (x.TermID.ToString()+ " " + x.UserID.ToString() + " " + x.CourseID.ToString() + " " + x.StudentID.ToString() + x.ObjectiveID.ToString())) and I got "identifier expected error at the i.ArtifactID != null, pointing to the '!=' symbols".

Comment: Try to replace '!= null' on 'IsNot Nothing', and do not forget to add 'x => ' in the beginning of the lambda expression.

Comment: Could someone please translate the original query into query expression syntax and not method-based syntax, for VB, if possible? Thank you!